# How to insert owner name in Account?

Tags: insert, owner

I have tried inserting a new record with ownerId and also with ownerName.But using "Ownername" shows the below error

```
  Account acc=new Account(Name='nEW',OwnerId='00528000001IpTb');
        insert acc;
        Account acc1=new Account(Name='nEW',Account__r.owner.firstname='gSS');
        insert acc;
```

> Invalid field initializer: Account__r.owner.firstname

How can I use OwnerName instead of OwnerId?Or is there any work around?

Comment: When you first instantiate an account you can't set a related records field value like that. You would have to requery and change the field directly if I'm not mistaken

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure what you are trying to do, can you clarify? Edit your post with more details

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is on this line

```
Account acc1=new Account(Name='nEW',Account__r.owner.firstname='gSS');
```

There is no relationship `account__r.owner.firstname`

The relationship is `account.owner.somefieldonUser`

and even so, when you insert an sobject, you can only instantiate fields directly on that sobject

so what you need is:

```
Account acc1=new Account(Name='nEW',ownerId = someExpressionThatderivesAnOwnerId);
```

Once the Account has an ownerId, you can query the Account to discover things about the owner:

```
[select id, owner.firstname, owner.lastname, owner.alias from Account where someWhereExpression]
```

Comment: And if queue ownership is enabled?

Comment: @adrianlarson can you have accounts owned by queues? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrESAA0

Comment: Woah. Didn't realize it's not an option. 7 years!? Such a simple request...

Comment: @AdrianLarson (BTW - nice to see you back) in my experience, territories is a more robust way to handle multi-user 'ownership'  of accounts so I can see why sfdc is dragging their heels

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I just assumed polymorphism was at play. :)